# User returns to previous screen instead of showing side menu

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, side-menu

I have the following situation: there is a screen, where I want to add side menu. Probably I had a lot of problems while integrating side-menu to my app, but now I created simple menu with one button. So, I want to open my side menu by swiping to the right side, but when I do it, I navigate to screen, which is higher in navigation. I didn't add side menu anywhere in navigation, as I don't understand where it should be. I just added it to render function. And at the 'highest' in navigation screen this menu is shown correctly. Probably I don't know which code should I attach, that is why ask for code I need to show and I will add it. Thanks in advance!

**UPD**

Here's my app navigator:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import AuthorizationScreen from '../screens/AuthorizationScreen';
import MainTabNavigator from './MainTabNavigator';


export default createAppContainer(
  createSwitchNavigator({
    // You could add another route here for authentication.
    // Read more at https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html
    // Authorization: AuthorizationScreen,
    Main: MainTabNavigator,
  })
);
```

Comment: What are you using `react-navigation` or `react-naive-navigation`?

Comment: @fayeed, react navigation. Updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IOS when you swipe from left it should go back to the previous screen that's the default behavior, so for that `react-navigation` provides a prop called `gestureEnabled` which is used to implement this behavior

> Whether you can use gestures to dismiss this screen. Defaults to true on iOS, false on Android.

In your Stack Navigator set navigation options like so:

```
Example: {
    name: 'Example Screen',
    screen: ExampleView
    navigationOptions: {
        gesturesEnabled: false,
    },
},
```

As for how and where should you add the drawer you can add it to your `MainTabNavigator` like so:

```
const MainTabNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Profile: ProfileScreen,
  },
  {
    intialRouteName: 'Home',
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(
  createSwitchNavigator({
    Main: MainTabNavigator,
  })
);
```